# Get the notification message when an windows phone 8.1 silverlight application is running in background

Tags: c#, silverlight, parse-platform, notifications, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a windows phone 8.1 silverlight application and there i'm using parse push notification. The push notification is working fine when the application is open.But, when the application is running as a background application then how can I get the notification body message or text from that notification view?

Here is the code that is working when the application is open.

```
 ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (sender, args) => {
      var payload = args.Payload;
      object objectId;
      if (payload.TryGetValue("alert", out objectId)){
           MessageBox.Show(objectId.ToString());
      }
 };
```

Now, I want to get the message of the notification when the application is running in background.I want to know how to handle the notification when the application is running as in background.

Answer (score 0):

Your app does not run in the background. It gets suspended when you leave it. You can receive raw notifications only when you app is running. the best thing you can do is to send a toast notifications and when your user taps on it an activates the app you poll the server to get the data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If I go by your advice how do I open a specific page when the notification is tap'd ?

Comment: WP8.1 Silverlight apps can also run a background process called 'ScheduledTaskAgent'. This activates every 30 minutes and can display a toast notification to users.